# Setting Toolbar Name for Activities extending BaseActivity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a baseActivity to which all my activities extend to. My activity label (Toolbar Name) doesn't appear on the toolbar. How can i set the toolbar names  in all the activities. I have been trying a lot to figure this out.  How do i set toolbar names for every activity?

**BaseActivity**

This is where i set the toolbar for the application

```
[Activity(Label = "Base")]

public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    toolBar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);
}
```

**Activity extending BaseActivity**

```
[Activity(Label = "MyName", Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]

public class Activity : BaseActivity
{

    toolbarMain = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);         
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);

    toolBar.SetTitle("MyName");
}
```

**Update of Activity extending BaseActivity**

```
protected  override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {


            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.content_frame);
            LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, content);

            toolbarMain = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);         

            SetSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);

            toolbarMain.SetTitle("MyName");

            setUpRecyclerView();

        }
```

Comment: are you getting any error?? or Title is not Set

Comment: The title is not set. I have a string in my resources. so i call it `toolBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.name)` but it is not set

Comment: Just do hardcoding to check

toolBar.SetTitle("Title");Let me know it Works or not?

Comment: it shows an error.. cannot convert string to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Toolbar custom**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_navi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarlogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="118dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/white1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbartitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Add the Toolbar layout whereever you needed it;like as below**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edu_hunt);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolBarLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.toolbarlogo);
        toolBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbartitle);
}
```

> Try Add this this may help you.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio, Xamarin

Comment: Does onCreate function is needed or not??in Xamrinn

Comment: Can you please Add Whole Code?

Comment: there is also Alternative ,you can use Custom Toolbar and Add the Layout Wherever it is necessary.Have you tried this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148034/discussion-between-seon-and-xamarinlearner).